# Hey can someone help understanding this topic! U sub versus no U sub!

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I want to understand how these two integrals are equal
say we integrate $$\int(x-10)dx$$
if we do it normally we will get $$\frac12x^2-10x$$
however we can also u-sub to save time $$\int u du$$ where u is x-10
and get $$\frac12(x-10)^2$$
How are these equivalent

Comment: The results only differ by a constant.

Comment: $$\frac12(x-10)^2=\frac12x^2-10x+100,$$ which differs from the first result by a constant, $100.$

Comment: thanks yall, this trick helped me alot with definite integrals on my last homework lol.